# I need a concrete footing to be 5 feet tall. What circumference and reinforcement do I need?

Tags: deck, footings

I am building a deck which will be 24 feet off the ground.  In order to use shorter posts can I build footings that will be approx. 5 feet tall from the soil line?  If so, how wide around (circumference) should the footing be and what is the best way to reinforce it?  And, how deep should the footing be underground?

Comment: This is the type of question that begs for so much more information. The only correct answer I can come up with is, "consult an engineer".

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate Agreed, especially for deck which, if it collapses, will likely kill people.

Comment: Definitely and engineer question.  They will spec the concrete diameter and probably rebar reinforcement required to keep the thing in one piece under lateral load.

Answer (score 2):

when you are building things 24 feet up and asking these kind of questions, it should be self evident you need to hire someone to do it for you or at the very least handle the technical design and ensure that what gets built is inspected and checked to make sure it matches the design specifications.

do yourself and any of your future guests and neighbours a favour, and get an architect and a general contractor involved.